# How are VPS connected directly to WAN?

Tags: linux, vps, wide-area-network

How is it that a VPS can be connected to WAN (Wide area network) without port forwarding?

Answer (score 3):

The physical interface of the host machine acts as a virtual switch (a bridge, really) where the virtual interfaces of the VPS are connected to. This way, you can connect multiple virtual interfaces with just one physical one.